# Is a macro that puts the contents of a form into a string possible?

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp

I'd like to write a macro that treats its arguments as a string.

```
(defmacro args->string (&rest args)
  "Change all arguments into strings and combine them."
  (nlp/auto-generate-code-based-on-doc))
```

Then I could write code like:

```
(python> import numpy as np) ;= nil
(python> np.array([1, 2, 3])) ;= [1 2 3]
(R> rnorm(100)) ;= [0.234223 0.44234 ...]
(hy> (+ 1 1)) ;= 2
```

that does inter-process communication through the already existing `inferior-process` framework.

Is this even possible in Emacs lisp?

Comment: You could start with something like this: `(defmacro args->string (&rest args) (mapconcat (apply-partially 'format "%S") args " "))` Though it needs to handle a few more special cases.  Why do you want to do this, instead of just passing a string to start with?

Comment: It is wonderful news to me that at least that much is possible! What special cases did you notice this doesn't cover?

Comment: I want to do this for the usual reasons people like to use macros: to make the syntax more pleasant to work with by hiding uninteresting details.  Also, escaping quotes is a pain in the butt ;-)

Comment: It puts backslashes in front of dots in symbols, and commas are escaped and put into small lists.  `(args->string np.array([1, 2, 3]))` returns:
`"np\\.array ([1 (\\, 2) (\\, 3)])"`

Comment: Have any ideas on how to recognize commas and other lisp syntax in general? Or is total generalization a lost cause? If only I could treat the form as a buffer, then all I'd have to do is insert some quotes and be on my way...

Comment: What you really want for this sort of thing is a Common Lisp-style [reader macro](https://gist.github.com/chaitanyagupta/9324402), which works directly on the program text as a character stream (rather than an already-read sequence of Lisp objects).  However, Emacs Lisp doesn't have reader macros.  You are probably best off using strings.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, this is not possible without hacking the Emacs Lisp reader.

Lisp evaluation proceeds in three steps: first, the characters are converted into list structure — this is called *reading*.  Then, all macros are expanded.  Finally, the resulting list structure is evaluated.

By the time a macro is called, the input has already been converted into list structure, and a fair amount of information about the original input has been lost; it is impossible in general to recover the original input at this stage.

As mentioned by Jon O., what you need is to hook earlier, at the reading stage.  This is possible in Common Lisp using *reader macros*, but is not supported by Emacs Lisp.